I found a counterexample to one of the intermediate assertions in a proof but not (necessarily) to the overall result – how to publish this?
I am working on a paper which builds upon work from a paper from the 1980s.
In that paper, a result of the form A < B < C is claimed in generality and is necessary for the proof of a result.
I have a counterexample wherein A > B but A < C, and the result technically still holds for my particular example, but it demonstrates that their way of proof fails in generality.
Is this worth including in a paper generalizing their results? Or is it better to just send to the journal that published the previous paper? I attempted to reach the authors of the previous paper multiple times but have received no response.

Depending on the social proximity of you and the people of the previous paper, it can be good to start a conversation with these authors and even invite them in your counterexample proof paper.

@StubbornSnail the paper is from the 80's and the authors have failed to respond to our attempts to reach them.

@AnotherPerson Oh yeah in this case it does not seem worth it or even feasible. My comment applies more to the "we are contemporary researchers so let's meet up and talk" case

Why not publish it? You're showing their proof is incorrect.

I think the latest edit to the headline question is now inconsistent with the actual question of the OP. I suggest "assumption" is incorrect and suggest something like "conjecture" or "claim" is better.

Do they actually claim that the final result requires A<B<C, or do they claim that their proof is valid only if A<B<C?

@jcaron, my reading is the intention of the OP is the former. That is, a necessary condition. That is the only way it is a counterexample. For a sufficient condition (or an assumption), it isn't a counterexample at all.

I'm actually unclear on what the error was. Is the error that "A < B < C is claimed in generality", but you found a counterexample to that (so, the equality doesn't hold in general)? Or is the error that "A < B < C is ... is necessary for the proof" but you have an example where "A > B but A < C, and the result technically still holds" (so, the inequality is not a necessary condition)? Or, something else? It might not matter in terms of how to proceed, but just to be clear that there actually is an error.

I agree OP’s description is unclear. My interpretation is the paper claims “if X then Y”, and the proof argues “if X, then A<B<C, therefore Y”. But OP found an example where X is satisfied, Y is also satisfied, but A<B<C is not satisfied, demonstrating that the paper’s proof is invalid, but not actually demonstrating that the stated theorem is incorrect. OP, can you confirm/clarify if this description fits your situation?

@Buffy: My interpretation is the same as Dan Romik’s. In my own words: The main proof is basically A < B < C ⇒ Y (for some class of cases), where the latter is the main result. This proof thus assumes A < B < C, and this assumption is either taken for granted or shown separately (wrongly, if the asker is correct). The asker found a case where A > B and thus has a counter-example to the proof’s assumption. However for that particular case, Y still holds. So, if the main proof is correct, A < B < C is sufficient for Y but not necessary.

@DanRomik that is the exact situation I am describing. The argument in the proof is incorrect but we are left in limbo with regards to whether the result is actually true or not.

This is about the content of research, and therefore off-topic, but will get a pass because it's about math.

You may be interested in Lakatos' concept of "local but not global counterexamples"; see e.g. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lakatos/

@AzorAhai-him- hmm, you're right. I didn't even realize this is off-topic if not for being math.

@AzorAhai: I do not see this. A question about the content of research would involve the details of the proof, the counter-example, etc. This is about whether this is publishable and where and thus the actual research is irrelevant. The only reason the field is not completely interchangeable is that (most) other fields do not have a rigorous proof structure and field-specific customs matter.

Currently the title says "Can I publish this as a paper", but the text says "including in a paper generalizing their results". These are quite different to the point that some may give opposite answers, so I recommend to bring title and question in line.

@Wrzlprmft The question here is - as far as I can tell - "Is this novel enough to publish, or should I just send it to the authors?" This is about the content of research. If I asked the question "My questionnaire didn't show the same factor structure in my sample of participants, should I publish or email the authors?" it would be immediately closed.

@AzorAhai: There are two steps to deciding publishability: estimating the impact (as in consequences, not as in impact factor) of a finding, and determining the value of findings with such impact in general. The first part is not suitable for this site, the second one is. Here, the asker has clearly outlined the impact and thus done the first step, which is how it should be. In your example, this can be done as well with some extra information on how strong the difference between the findings is, etc. This is easier in mathematics, since a proof equally falls with any of its components.

@Wrzlprmft I do not think the OP has "clearly outlined the impact," unless you happen to be a mathematician.

Yes. For example, in 1966, Lander and Parkin published a counterexample to Euler's conjecture on sums of like powers in the Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, which is somewhat famous for being one of the shortest papers ever published.

More such short examples are here.

I don’t think what OP is describing is a counterexample in the strong sense you’re describing. See my other comment where I asked them to clarify.

(In other words, your “proof” in this answer that OP can publish a paper seems incorrect, but your conclusion may still be correct, similarly to what I suspect OP’s situation is…)

I also agree with them comments by Dan Romik. This answer is not really relevant to the actual question by the OP. The question is not about settling an established conjecture, but more about correcting an error in the literature.

It’s tempting to try how long it takes to find this counter example on a modern computer. CDC 6600 would have been 1966. And find out how much of a coincidence this counter example was.

@gnasher729: I wonder what the search space was. Were they only looking for 4 powers of 5? Or other permutations of counts and/or powers?

It's amusing when that paper is brought up because it isn't a good example: it would be considered unethical salami slicing today. The real paper is L. Lander & T. Parkin, "A counterexample to Euler's sum of powers conjecture," Math. Comp., v. 21, 1967, pp. 101-103, mentioned here, which describes the algorithm and other results. They sliced one sentence to a new paper. (Doing this was more acceptable in the days of print journals and lack of metrics)

@user71659 when you disprove a conjecture of Euler’s, I suspect that the usual “metrics” don’t really apply, and no one will particularly care how you choose to publish your results, even today.

@user71659: I think you have a misunderstanding here, this has nothing to do with salami slicing. At the time, it was common to publish short "research announcements" in journals such as Bulletin AMS. These would simply state the results, with little detail about the proofs. The actual paper with full details would then appear in a different journal. Today announcements like this are less common, since we have things like the arXiv.

People here are referring to OP's discovery as a "counterexample", but I think it's useful to point out that "counterexample" can be used to refer to three distinct types of things:

Someone makes a conjecture that all mathematical objects belonging to some class X satisfy property Y. I later find an object from class X that doesn't satisfy Y. That's a counterexample that disproves a conjecture.

Someone proves a theorem stating that all objects belonging to some class X satisfy property Y. I later find an object from class X that doesn't satisfy Y. That's a counterexample that invalidates a theorem. It demonstrates that the previously claimed "theorem" is actually not a theorem at all, since it is a false statement, and therefore also shows that the earlier claimed proof must necessarily contain a mistake.

Someone proves a theorem stating that all objects belonging to some class X satisfy property Y. I later find a mistake in the proof. This  demonstrates that the proof is invalid, but doesn't demonstrate that the theorem is false. The theorem may be false, or it may be true - we revert to an earlier state of not knowing whether it's true or false.
This type of invalidation of proofs (which is not uncommon) is not really a "counterexample" in a general sense. But in OP's particular situation, OP seems to have demonstrated that the proof is invalid, by finding a counterexample to a subclaim used as part of the purported proof. As they clarified in a comment, the situation is roughly: the theorem in the original paper claimed: "if X, then Y", and the proof reasons as follows: "if X, then A<B<C, therefore Y". OP found a counterexample to the "if X, then A<B<C" subclaim, by finding an object satisfying X but for which the A<B<C (intermediate) conclusion is false. This shows that step in the reasoning of the proof to be invalid. However, since the object satisfying X also satisfies Y in OP's case, it leaves open the question of whether the statement of the "theorem" (which now would be more properly classified as a "conjecture" or "assertion") is correct.


Now, to address your question of whether a "counterexample", in any of the 3 senses discussed above, can/should be published. The answers are: yes, yes, and yes. For a situation of type 1, @DanielRCollins's answer provides an example (or perhaps I should say a "proof by example"...). People finding counterexamples of conjectures is something that happens practically all the time. Here's one other well-known example.
Situations of type 2 are a bit less common, but still happen occasionally. Here is a list of stories about such situations from a MathOverflow discussion. And the same goes for situations of type 3, which are listed in their own MathOverflow thread.
In all of these types of situations, the discovery of the "counterexample" was new knowledge that was of interest to mathematicians, and deserved to be shared with the community, usually through the standard mechanism for sharing new knowledge, which is publishing the results. In some cases this was a major discovery, in other cases only of marginal interest to anyone (which is also the case for many "ordinary" new results), but at least by default it should be regarded as being at least as publishable as any other legitimate new research on a similar topic.

perhaps the distinctions made by Lakatos, of local vs global counterexamples, may be of use to this discussion. (See the first enumerated list of section 3.1 here for a summary: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lakatos/#ProoRefu19631976)

@JohnMadden indeed, thanks for the reference. My classification does seem surprisingly similar to his.

Yes, counter examples are welcome to be published as they correct the record.
They are especially important if they give insight into why the original fails. Adding that insight would be helpful and welcome.
It is worth doing a search, of course, to assure yourself that what you have isn't already published.

The paper where you generalize the results would be the best place to point out the error/mistake in the older paper from the 1980s. Others can then cite your work as a reference for the correct proof, and there is no need to publish an erratum.
The alternative is to attempt to publish separately some kind of comment/erratum, but in mathematics publishing such things is unfortunately rare, and usually the original authors would be involved.
You might also find it difficult to get a comment/erratum published, and it might even be rejected if it is not considered significant enough.
